# Sunni's view on Ghadir Khumm

Tags: hadith-interpretation, sunni, shia-sunni

Shia's view on Ghadir Khumm produces the idea that Ali is the only legitimate successor directly after Muhammad. What is the Sunnis view on this? Why don't they consider Ghadir Khumm as serious as Shias do?